# Use keycloak verify the Opentelemetry exporter to receiver's connection

Tags: oauth-2.0, keycloak, openid-connect, tls1.2, open-telemetry-collector

Yes，This question named same as [How to secure OpenTelemetry endpoint with Keycloak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76103539/how-to-secure-opentelemetry-endpoint-with-keycloak?newreg=c68d7511eb4c4cbaba5385502a1391af).

But this question`s point is different from that one.

By now, the OpenTelemetry is arrived at 0.90.1, and the keycloak has now been released to 23.0.1.

How to use those tools make a secure connection to send/put tracing data between any nodes.

Let us set the deploy :

- App with inside Opentelemetry Sdk ，who can produce tracing data and send out the app.Let`s name it like InsideAppExporter.
- Opentelemetry collector works like agent ,Let`s Name it Collector.
- Opentelemetry collector works like another agent,Let`s Name it Agent.
- keycloak server deploy on anyone,In my maind i`d deploy it on the Agent node.
- I have run this flow without keycloak in a no secure link well.but it`s not suite of the rule.

All I want is connection with tls,and the incoming request is authenticated.

Can you help with an example flow that makes sense?

Maybe some helpful links:

1. The one before [How to secure OpenTelemetry endpoint with Keycloak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76103539/how-to-secure-opentelemetry-endpoint-with-keycloak)
2. [Securing your OpenTelemetry Collector](https://medium.com/opentelemetry/securing-your-opentelemetry-collector-1a4f9fa5bd6f),it`s out of date.
3. [Authenticator - OAuth2 Client Credentials](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/extension/oauth2clientauthextension):config exporter inside Client[Collector]
4. [Authenticator - OIDC](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/extension/oidcauthextension):config receiver inside server[Agent]
5. [cfssl cloudflare](https://github.com/cloudflare/cfssl): generate ssl key

Comment: I can`t email you [jpkroehling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/524946/jpkroehling) can you post another aritcle like the Securing your OpenTelemetry Collector

Answer (score 0):

OAuth is an authorization framework, based on protecting (business) data based on scopes and claims issued to access tokens.

Whereas your scenario requires only an authentication solution. So OAuth is overkill I would say, and infrastructure security should be sufficient.

For example, if running in Kubernetes I would use the kind of built in mutual TLS security provided by a service mesh. This would typically be implemented by sidecars and transparent to the components themselves.

In other environments I would aim to emulate that model. Eg the OpenTelemetry client might route requests via a forward proxy that attaches a client certificate.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The plan you mentioned is feasible and the most streamlined implementation plan.
Add keycloak, however, and other apps can be accessed easily. Because there is not only one endpoint that needs to be identified, and the messages sent from each endpoint are segmented.

Answer (score 0):

## 英文版

1. Basics: App --> jaeger
2. Advanced: App --> Collector --> jaeger | another|more Collector --> jaeger
3. Certification: App --> Collector --> jaeger | another|more Collector --> jaeger

   ```
    ---------request with secret key---- verify the request if valid then accept -----
   ```

Encrypt the entire link from Collector to Collector (tls) and authenticate incoming requests (keycloak).

### Deploy keycloak service:

```
 Deploy directly in docker:
     v16.1.1 docker run -p 8080:8080 -e KEYCLOAK_USER=admin -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:16.1.1
     v23.0.1 docker run -p 8080:8080 -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:23.0.1 start-dev
```

If you use the command

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -e KEYCLOAK_USER=admin -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:23.0.1 start-dev
```

the following prompt will appear if it is deployed on an interfaceless server. Then you will encounter the following prompt during this deployment. It is recommended to use the previous command to specify admin&password at startup.

```
             You need local access to create the initial admin user.
             Open http://localhost:8080/
             or set the environment variables KEYCLOAK_ADMIN and KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD before starting the server
```

Service initialization will take some time, so please wait a moment. Or follow the log directly to view the running status.

After the service is started, open the keycloak web management interface.
Proceed as follows:

```
     Reference page:
         https://www.keycloak.org/getting-started/getting-started-docker
         V16.1.1 https://medium.com/opentelemetry/securing-your-opentelemetry-collector-1a4f9fa5bd6f
     Main operations:
         V23.0.1
         1. Log in to the management interface and use the username and password initialized in the above command;
         <!-- 1. Click <Administration Console> use admin admin to login -->
         2. Add realm: opentelemetry
         3. Switch to realm: opentelemetry
         4. Add clients:
             4.1 Collector
                 Just fill in the Client ID: Collector --> save, done.
             4.2 agents
                 Fill in the Client ID: agent -->Next

                 <Client authentication> change to On for the confidential type [This defines the type of the OIDC client. When it's ON, the OIDC type is set to confidential access type. When it's OFF, it is set to public access type]
                 <Standard flow> check off [needn`t browser logoin This enables standard OpenID Connect redirect based authentication with authorization code. In terms of OpenID Connect or OAuth2 specifications, this enables support of 'Authorization Code Flow' for this client.]
                 <Service accounts roles> check on [Allows you to authenticate this client to Keycloak and retrieve access token dedicated to this client. In terms of OAuth2 specification, this enables support of 'Client Credentials Grant' for this client.]
                 -->Next -->Save
                 agent --> <Credentials> --Client Secret -- Copy out to other place or remember we will use it later. now we init it as ABABCCC
                 then check tab <Client Scopes> #v23.0.1
                     Client Scopes -- <agent-dedicated> -->Click it ,We go to the deep page for mapper.
                         Add mapper -->By Configuration --> select <audience>
                             name: whatever you want, it`s not important
                             <Included Client Audience>: select <collector> ,it`s important!
                         --> Save
                     Another Way to create the audience #v23.0.1:
                         Manage -- <Client Scopes> -- Create client scope : whatever you want, it`s not important ,<Protocol-OpenId Connect> -->Save
                         Check to tab <Mappers> -- Configure a new mapper -- select <Audience> ,then take a name whatever you want.
                         Included Client Audience: select <collector> ,it`s important!
                         --> Save
```

Got Back to Clients -- agent --  Add the one created before.

Now,We have two client inside keycloak. one named collector, one named agent. and the collector is one audience of agent.

There is one secret key that needs to be used externally: ABABCCCC, an agent, and a collector.

There are also two certification addresses:

```
         #v16.1.1
             collector http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/opentelemetry/protocol/openid-connect/token
             agent http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/opentelemetry
         #v23.0.1
             collector http://host:port/realms/{realm-name}/protocol/openid-connect/token
             agent http://host:port/realms/{realm-name}
```

### Generate certificate:

```
 cfssl
     Create two original files
     ca-csr.json context equal with cert-csr.json
         {
             "hosts": [
                 "localhost",
                 "127.0.0.1",
                 "10.10.10.102",
                 "ubuntu22op.com",
                 "10.10.10.103"
             ],
             "key": {
                 "algo": "rsa",
                 "size": 2048
             },
             "names": [
                 {
                     "O": "OpenTelemetry Collector"
                 }
             ]
         }
```

Note: The address or domain name in the hosts array must contain the host IP or domain name where the agent is located. If all services are deployed on the same host, the first two should be sufficient. The domain name in my configuration is fake and is a local domain name; it is handed over directly to the router.
Directly resolved to the local. The actual address of ubuntu22op.com locally is 10.10.10.142, if you also expect to use the domain name. Consider hijacking/intercepting domain names for resolution within the router address of your home or company.

```
     Generate certificate
         cfssl genkey -initca ca-csr.json | cfssljson -bare ca
         cfssl gencert -ca ca.pem -ca-key ca-key.pem cert-csr.json | cfssljson -bare cert
     Now, there are 4 files.
     ca.pem(copy it to the collector machine, node, folder): collector named collector will use
     ca-key.pem
     cert.pem(copy it to the agent machine, node, folder): collector named agent will use
     cert-key.pem(copy it to the agent machine, node, folder): collector named agent will use
```

### Change configuration:
Collector

```
     collector_config.yaml
         extensions:
             oauth2client:
                 client_id: agent
                 client_secret: ABABCCC
                 token_url: http://10.10.10.103:8080/realms/opentelemetry/protocol/openid-connect/token #v23.0.1
                 #v23.0.1/realms/{realm-name}/protocol/openid-connect/token

         receivers:
             otlp:
                 protocols:
                 grpc:
                 http:

         processors:
             batch:
                 send_batch_size: 10000
                 timeout: 10s

         exporters:
             otlp/withauth:
             endpoint: https://ubuntu22op.com:4317
             tls:
                 ca_file: ./ca.pem
             auth:
                 authenticator:oauth2client

         service:
             extensions: [oauth2client]
             pipelines:
                 traces:
                     receivers: [otlp]
                     processors:
                         -batch
                     exporters:
                         -otlp/withauth
```

Change configuration:
agent

```
     agent_config.yaml
         extensions:
             oidc:
                 issuer_url: http://10.10.10.103:8080/realms/opentelemetry #v23.0.1
                 audience: collector
                 attribute: authorization

         receivers:
             otlp/withauth:
                 protocols:
                 grpc:
                     # endpoint: localhost:4317 #Note that if it is explicitly written as localhost:4317, the front-end collector cannot establish a connection when TLS requires authentication. The reason is currently unknown (2023-12-9 21:52:36), and we look forward to it being resolved in the future. After all, if the situation is not clear, there will be warnings and it is easy to be attacked.
                     tls:
                         cert_file: ./cert.pem
                         key_file: ./cert-key.pem
                     auth:
                         authenticator: oidc

         processors:
             batch:
                 send_batch_size: 10000
                 timeout: 10s

         exporters:
             otlp/jaeger:
                 endpoint: 10.10.10.102:4317 # server22 with signoz
                 tls:
                     insecure: true


         service:
             extensions: [oidc]
             pipelines:
                 traces:
                 receivers: [otlp/withauth]
                 processors:
                     -batch
                 exporters:
                     -otlp/jaeger
```

Sort out the location of service deployment:

1.app don’t care

2.collector 10.10.10.103

3.agent 10.10.10.142 (https://ubuntu22op.com:4317)

4.jaeger 10.10.10.102:4317

At Last, it’s time to witness the results of your efforts:

```
 1. First run the keycloak service
     v16.1.1 docker run -p 8080:8080 -e KEYCLOAK_USER=admin -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:16.1.1
     v23.0.1 docker run -p 8080:8080 -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:23.0.1 start-dev
         If you use the command docker run -p 8080:8080 -e KEYCLOAK_USER=admin -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:23.0.1 start-dev, the following prompt will appear if it is deployed on an interfaceless server. Then you will encounter the following prompt during this deployment. It is recommended to use the previous command to specify admin&password at startup.
             You need local access to create the initial admin user.
             Open http://localhost:8080/
             or set the environment variables KEYCLOAK_ADMIN and KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD before starting the server
 2. Run the Collector named agent again.
      ./otelcol-contrib --config ./agent_config.yaml
      All Good With Msg: Everything is ready. Begin running and processing data.
 3. Run the Collector named collector again.
     ./otelcol-contrib --config ./collector_config.yaml
     All Good With Msg: Everything is ready. Begin running and processing data.
 Maybe it will look good ,and will not work well. just checkout your config more and more times.
 4. Run the App and change tracing-jaeger again to any character to distinguish it.
```